# how to delete a ListView item using a button created inside that item.

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a class which has a Listview. The ListView is populated using a pattern.xml file which has a button in it. when the class is called the Button gets copied for each item in the listview. now what i want is to access those button to delete the corresponding item from the list. so how can i do that? Please help me to solve this. The code for that class is  given bellow.

```
public class Secondscreen extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen); 
    ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    final Button thirdBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.third);


    final Controller aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        final int cartSize = aController.getCart().getCartSize();

        final ArrayList<Listitem> arrayList=new ArrayList<Listitem>();


         BaseAdapter adapter= new BaseAdapter(){

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arrayList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arrayList.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
                if (view == null) {
                    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pattern, null);
                }
                TextView tv=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameview);
                TextView tv2=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdesc);
                TextView tv3=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceView);



                tv.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
                tv2.setText(""+arrayList.get(position).getPrice());
                tv3.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDesc());
                return view;
            }       

        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        if(cartSize >0)
            {   

                for(int i=0;i<cartSize;i++)
                {

                   String pName   = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductName();
                   int pPrice      = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductPrice();
                   String pDisc       = aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getProductDesc();

                    Listitem item=new Listitem(pName, pPrice, pDisc);
                    arrayList.add(item);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `OnClickListener` of `Button` and remove Item from `arrayList` in your `BaseAdapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
            if (view == null) {
                view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pattern, null);
            }
            Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
            //button.setTag(position);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Integer position = (Integer)view.getTag();
                    arrayList.remove(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            // Your other views...
            return view;
        }
```

Comment: I know that but i can not figure out where to put those code in. how can i get access to any particular button in the list to apply an on click action on it.

Comment: I have tried the above procedure already and i get an error in adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); line and it says "The local variable adapter may not have been initialized" and i don't know how to do that.

Comment: just add `final` before `BaseAdapter adapter = ...` line

Comment: Actually your code is bit messy... But this can be quick fix for existing code.

Comment: i did that as well and the error that i mentioned above comes after putting the final keyword before BaseAdapter adapter = ... line.And sorry for being messy with code. can not help it. I guess it is understandable.

Comment: add `BaseAdapter self = this;` before your `setOnClickListener` and call `self.notifyDataSetChanged();` instead of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`